# MS Access VBA Referring to controls on a sub report using 'with'

Tags: vba, ms-access, with-statement, subreports

Using MS Access VBA the following code works for me:

```
Reports.PARENT_REPORT_NAME.CHILD_REPORT_NAME.Report.Label1.Caption = "Yes"
```

However this does not:

```
With Reports(PARENT_REPORT_NAME)
.CHILD_REPORT_NAME.Report.Label1.Caption = "Yes"
```

Does anyone have any insight for me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the [Reports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/reports-object-access) collection and [Report.Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/report-controls-property-access) property which allow string references of object names:

```
With Reports("PARENT_REPORT_NAME")                
   .Controls("CHILD_REPORT_NAME").Report.Label1.Caption = "Yes"
   ...
End With
```